# AVFoundation Video Camera crashes when returning to view controller Swift 4

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift4, viewcontroller

I'm creating an app that users AVFoundation to record a video. I have a Login View Contoller which leads to a View Controller (user can see their profile details here) which leads to a Data Collection View Controller (this is where the video camera is presented). All works fine but when I click on a back button to go back to the View Controller, and then click 'start data collection' to go back into the video camera a 2nd time, the app crashes.

Crash info:

> 2018-08-11 11:39:51.861569+0100 LiopaDatacapture-iOS[6343:1642808] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureMetadataOutput
>   setMetadataObjectTypes:] Unsupported type found - use
>   -availableMetadataObjectTypes'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1842e6d8c 0x1834a05ec 0x189e54b44 0x10128f4fc 0x1012989a4 0x101298ca4 0x18df01e64 0x18df01a50
>   0x18eaa4fd8 0x18e12b398 0x18e12a25c 0x18e3a33a0 0x18e0e13e4
>   0x18e1297bc 0x18e129654 0x18e3a6350 0x18e734d24 0x18e881af4
>   0x18e8819a0 0x18e39a49c 0x101297f5c 0x18e05564c 0x18e176870
>   0x18e05b700 0x18e1911a8 0x18e0d89e0 0x18e0cd890 0x18e0cc1d0
>   0x18e8add1c 0x18e8b02c8 0x18e8a9368 0x18428f404 0x18428ec2c
>   0x18428c79c 0x1841acda8 0x186192020 0x18e1cc758 0x101284a90
>   0x183c3dfc0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException (lldb)

I'm using AVCaptureMetadataOutput to detect faces. This code is in my SessionHandler class where the video camera is being set up.

```
// define metadata
        let metaOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if cameraSession.canAddOutput(metaOutput) {
            metaOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: faceQueue)
            cameraSession.addOutput(metaOutput)
            print("metaoutput added")
        }

        // set metadata to look for faces
        metaOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.face]
```

In my DataCaptureViewController.swift file this is where I load the video camera-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sessionHandler.setupCamera()
    audioRecorder.setUpAudioSession()

    createObservers()

    let layer = sessionHandler.layer
    layer.frame = previewView.bounds
    previewView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    jsonSentence.text = "Press start button to get phrase"
    startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)

}
```

I've played around a bit trying viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear but I'm new to swift and don't think I fully understand what they do or if this is what's causing the problem.

The SessionHandler class variables need to be shared with an Objective-C class so I've created a shared instance of it to be used throughout the app.

```
static let sharedSession = SessionHandler()
```

It's hard to know what code is useful to share but if you need any more info I'm happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seemed pretty straightforward in the end, sorry for the big question!

It was because the metadataObjectTypes was empty when the DataCaptureViewController was reloaded. So I created a viewDidAppear method and set the metadataObjectTypes to face in there.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sessionHandler.setupCamera()
    audioRecorder.setUpAudioSession()

    createObservers()

    let layer = sessionHandler.layer
    layer.frame = previewView.bounds
    previewView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    jsonSentence.text = "Press start button to get phrase"
    startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)


}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    sessionHandler.metaOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.face]
}
```

The app seems to be working now. If I've done this incorrectly though feel free to correct!